# What's the accepted standard for scrollTop()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm seeing a lot of discrepancies for how to get the page's scroll position. Some documents/tutorials use this:

```
$('html, body').scrollTop()
```

Others use `$(document)` or `$(window)`. But for some reason, `$('html, body').scrollTop()` does not work in both Firefox and Chrome (I haven't even checked IE yet).

What is the universal accepted standard for this?

Comment: `$('html, body').scrollTop()` works for me in chrome.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan It returns `0` for me every time.

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop()` seems to be most preferred one. what is your jQuery version?

Comment: What are the values for `document.documentElement.scrollTop` or `document.body.scrollTop`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(window).scrollTop()`. While the other options you stated will work in most situations (maybe all?), `$(window)` is the most appropriate and semantic because you want to get the distance from the top of the `window` to the top of the `document`.